# Pyspark create testing data with string type

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, dataset

I am trying to create testing data frame with one column with Int and one column with String type. With output similar to below. I reckon for Int we could use

```
data = spark.range(1, 5)
output = dataset.withColumnRenamed('id','myid')
```

How do we deal with that string column? Many thanks for your help!

Expected output:

```
      id.     ordernum
       1       0032
       2       0033
       3       0034
       4       0035
       5       0036
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Spark dataframe from a list of lists. Here is an example:

```
data = [[i, '%04d' % (i+31)] for i in range(1,6)]
# [[1, '0032'], [2, '0033'], [3, '0034'], [4, '0035'], [5, '0036']]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'ordernum'])
df.show()
+---+--------+
| id|ordernum|
+---+--------+
|  1|    0032|
|  2|    0033|
|  3|    0034|
|  4|    0035|
|  5|    0036|
+---+--------+
```

If you prefer Spark range, you can use `format_string`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.range(1, 6).withColumn(
    'ordernum',
    F.format_string('%04d', F.col('id') + 31)
)

df.show()
+---+--------+
| id|ordernum|
+---+--------+
|  1|    0032|
|  2|    0033|
|  3|    0034|
|  4|    0035|
|  5|    0036|
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lpad` function to create `ordernum` column from `id + 31` column left padded with 0 to get a string number with 4 digits:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output = spark.range(1, 6).withColumn("ordernum", F.lpad(col("id") + 31, 4, '0'))

output.show()
#+---+--------+
#| id|ordernum|
#+---+--------+
#|  1|    0032|
#|  2|    0033|
#|  3|    0034|
#|  4|    0035|
#|  5|    0036|
#+---+--------+
```